# Magento get list of item SKUs from orders

Tags: magento

I know Magento orders can be attained with 
    `$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');`
but then how can I get the information for each order? The information I need most per order is: SKUs purchased, date purchased, money spent on each item, and discounts, if any.

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a direct answer

`Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');` retrieves collection of orders (`sales_flat_order`)

SKU is stored in sales_flat_order_item

From order you can get order items using method getAllVisibleItems (it will retrieve respective `sales_flat_order_item`) see the definition in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
foreach($orders as $order){
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku();
    }
}
```

The point is like that, you have to modify it by yourself.
For the money spent on each item, you can also take a look at `sales_flat_order_item`

Comment: just a reminder, I just gave clue to get all orders (sales_flat_order) and order items (sales_flat_order_item), for the detail info you need to take a look at those tables

Comment: For the most part, this works very well. However, although I am able to find the grand total in the var_dump of $item, $item->getGrandTotal() does not have any output. How can I get the grand total of an $item?

Comment: nope, there are not grand total in $item, you can use $item->getRowTotal(); instead